# "The Mental Math Challenge" can this be more efficient?

Tags: python, selenium, math

Recently I have been trying to improve my mental math capabilities and I came across this website, https://rankyourbrain.com/mental-math/mental-math-test-easy/countdown. User need to do as many simple math questions as possible within 2 minutes using only +, -, and / .After several trial, I decided to use python web scraping to automate the process to see how far computers could go on the leader-board. Here is my python code....

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from Num import NumericStringParser
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://rankyourbrain.com/mental-math/mental-math-test-easy/countdown')
time.sleep(6)
for x in range(0, 10000):
    content = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    number = soup.find(id="beforeAnswer").get_text()
    newstr = number.replace("=", "")
    nsp=NumericStringParser()
    result = int(nsp.eval(newstr))
    print(result)
    #time.sleep(0.1)
    username =browser.find_element_by_id("answer")
    username.send_keys(result)
```

I was only able to boost my score up to 2000 on a good run, seeing the code being not so efficient, I would like to ask if there is other more efficient way of doing this? Especially to score 16383 within 2 minutes the code must be really fast and efficient, so there is a lot more for me to learn I think:D

Comment: I like this question... it's about writing code to do something fun which is also educational. I'm actually surprised your code isn't faster considering you are using BeautifulSoup. I wrote mine in Java and got ~2200. What is in `NumericStringParser()`? I `split()` the `beforeAnswer` text by " " and grabbed x, operator, and y. Did a `switch` based on operator and performed the calculation to find the answer. I can post my Java answer if you'd like... I was hesitant to do so since you asked for python.

Comment: Hi, nice to see that you are also enjoyed the little challenge. NumericStringParser() is a function which I took from the internet that does similar calculations but is also capable of calculating sin cos etc. I think this can also be one reason why it is slower because it runs more checks. After changing the python code with split(), it is slightly faster reaching ~2100. It occurs to me that the bottle neck might be soup.find since it has to look for entire html file. I am trying now with something like xpath and hop it works faster.

Comment: The heart of this is the Calculator object in `https://rankyourbrain.com/js/app_1.js` It generates question-answer pairs and keeps an audit trail with timestamps, and sends the whole works for verification (ie you can't just set `rightAnswers` and submit it). If you really want to run up your score, you can reverse-engineer this to build a perfect-session audit-trail generator ;-)

Comment: XPath, at least for Java and C#, is slower than the traditional methods of locating by id, class, and the like. I generally avoid it because of this and it's more likely to be brittle (depending on how it's crafted, of course).